# Services on homescreen jailbroken iphone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, services

On my jailbroken iPhone 5 with ios 6.1.2 I sometimes see all kinds of services from applications filling up my homescreen. Most of the times this happens after installing an application. After a respring they will dissapear.

Example:

[image]

Tweaks I have installed are:

```
- %hooks law
- activator
- activedock
- auxo
- barrel
- blurriedncbackground
- ncsettings
- springtomize
```

Has anyone had this problem before and does someone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly common issue on jailbroken devices. It's a harmless bug where usually-hidden system apps suddenly show up, usually after installing a new app. I've seen reports of it happening on devices on iOS 6 with various combinations of tweaks installed, so I'm not sure whether any specific tweak is causing it, or whether it's related to the jailbreak itself. If you use Springtomize to hide Apple apps, you could try un-hiding those apps and seeing if the white icons come back (the hypothesis here is that maybe Springtomize's hidden apps feature is causing the problem for you).

Comment: Thanks, so there's no actual fix for this? I'm not hiding any apple apps. I do hide the spotlight so maybe it could be related to that? I will try if turning this off helps.